# Rest Assured Output : print URL

Tags: rest-assured

I would like to see which URL Rest assured has constructed for test.
My code is pretty vanilla.

```
ValidatableResponse response = given().
                        auth().preemptive().basic("User", "Passwd").
                        contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                        log().all().
                    when().
                        get("/ping").
                    then().
                        statusCode(200);
```

But the output is a heck of a stack trace which does not even tell me what was the target URL.

```
checkServer
"java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <200> doesn't match actual status code <500>.

    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:598)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:760)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:120)
    at com.jayway.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:128)
    at com.jayway.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:117)
    at org.mystuff.EnvironmentCheck.checkServer(EnvironmentCheck.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
... Removed 31 stack frames
```

How would I go about that?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. :)

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your request is using the default host and port number. From https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#default-values: "By default REST assured assumes host localhost and port 8080 when doing a request."

If you want to actually see what RESTAssured is sending, rather than just inferring, see https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#request-logging, which refers one to http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html to see "what's actually sent on the wire." That document, under "Configuration Examples", has different options for enabling HttpClient communications logging.

From that document, the quick solution best suited to your question send to be the "Enable header wire + context logging - Best for Debugging" set of JVM system properties:

```
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog 
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true 
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG 
-Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR`
```

Comment: No problem, but my question is how do I print the target URL?

Comment: You should probably be more specific in your question, then. :) Mental URL construction is a way of "seeing" the request URL.